# How do I get clicked item position of a listView which contains WebView in each row on Android?

Tags: android

```
chatListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
                       Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Position" + " " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        );
```

not working

only ontouch is working but how to get position

```
chatListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
```

Comment: could you please share the output you get after you use onitemclicklistener ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your **ListView Item Click Listener**

```
String selectedFromList =(listcontent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

This will get the position of the item and you can then get the view

Comment: onItemClickListener is not working on listView with WebView so please check it again